# Specflow: Generate report without running tests

Tags: report, cucumber, specflow

I want a list of scenarios that are present in my specflow automation project. I can use the test execution report. But I do not want to wait for 70 tests to run before I could get the report. 
I have used the `dry-run` tag with cucumber before. It doesn't run the tests. It scans through the tests and generates a JSON. 
Is there something similar for specflow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow does not have a built in way to generate a simple report of the scenario names.

If the built in SpecFlow.exe reports referenced in the other answers do not provide a suitable option, another alternative is to parse the feature files. An open-source library built for parsing SpecFlow feature files is [Pickles](http://www.picklesdoc.com/). Similar to Cucumber's [Relish](http://www.relishapp.com/), Pickles can be executed to generate a list of scenarios in a variety of formats including JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the `packages/SpecFlow-VERSION/tools/specflow.exe` command line utility has an option called `stepdefinitionreport` which might get you something similar.

[SpecFlow Reporting](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Reporting/)

```
C:\path\to\your\project> packages\SpecFlow\1.9.0\tools\specflow.exe stepdefinitionreport Your.AcceptanceTests.csproj
```

It should generate a file call StepDefinitionReport.html. It just spits out the step bindings and not a formatted version of your test suite.

The second option is to use the `nunitexecutionreport` option, but this requires you to have run the tests at least once (and to be using NUnit instead of MS Test) and will generate an HTML report.

```
C:\path\to\your\project> packages\SpecFlow\1.9.0\tools\specflow.exe nunitexecutionreport Your.AcceptanceTests.csproj /out:MyResult.html
```